# Is it possible to share and merge classification models?

Tags: machine-learning

I'm starting my machine learning study and I'm trying to figure out a simple question:

Let's say that I have two models, one that recognizes cats, and another one that recognize dogs.

Now I have a camera and I want to recognize both cats and dogs using my models.

Obviously, I don't want to create a third model to recognize both, having all the work to label each animal, so, is there a method to "merge" both models into one?

I'm asking this question because I want to understand one thing: why ML engineers don't share their models so then we can create aggregated models? For example, if a person A has a model that classifies people and a person B has a model for animals. Why they can't just share their models so then each one will have a more powerful model without needing to re-train everything?

I'm sorry if this is a too basic question, but I didn't see on Google any clear explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that I've found an answer [here](https://www.quora.com/Where-can-we-download-trained-machine-learning-models) and [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-combine-machine-learning-models).

Comment: Just to add to this, if you use pytorch, they have [an easy-to-use interface called model zoo](https://pytorch.org/serve/model_zoo.html) where you can download pretrained models.

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely can do this, and it is very often done in practice. Many models are publicly available, and since training takes a lot of time, a lot of ML engineers will use pretrained models to begin tackling their problem.

And your intuition is right, that re-training for the "combined" scenario would be a waste of time.

If you want some more reading, look into ensemble methods and transfer learning.